# how do I forecast data (in my case, rainfall) into the future after I have trained a model using scikit_learn and pandas?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, forecasting, sklearn-pandas

I am training a model to predict rainfall data into the future. I have completed the training of the model already.
I am using this dataset : https://www.kaggle.com/redikod/historical-rainfall-data-in-bangladesh
It looks like this :

```
              Station   Yea  Month Day Rainfall dayofyear
1970-01-01  1   Dhaka   1970    1   1   0           1
1970-01-02  1   Dhaka   1970    1   2   0           2
1970-01-03  1   Dhaka   1970    1   3   0           3
1970-01-04  1   Dhaka   1970    1   4   0           4
1970-01-05  1   Dhaka   1970    1   5   0           5
```

I have completed the training using train and test data by using a code I found online as a reference. And then I have also checked the predicted value against true value.

Here is the code,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf

#data is in local folder
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
df.head(5)

df.drop(df[(df['Day']>28) & (df['Month']==2) & (df['Year']%4!=0)].index,inplace=True)
df.drop(df[(df['Day']>29) & (df['Month']==2) & (df['Year']%4==0)].index,inplace=True)
df.drop(df[(df['Day']>30) & ((df['Month']==4)|(df['Month']==6)|(df['Month']==9)|(df['Month']==11))].index,inplace=True)

date = [str(y)+'-'+str(m)+'-'+str(d) for y, m, d in zip(df.Year, df.Month, df.Day)]
df.index = pd.to_datetime(date)
df['date'] = df.index
df['dayofyear']=df['date'].dt.dayofyear
df.drop('date',axis=1,inplace=True)

df.head()
df.size()
df.info()

df.plot(x='Year',y='Rainfall',style='.', figsize=(15,5))

train = df.loc[df['Year'] <= 2015]
test = df.loc[df['Year'] == 2016]
train=train[train['Station']=='Dhaka']
test=test[test['Station']=='Dhaka']

X_train=train.drop(['Station','StationIndex','dayofyear'],axis=1)
Y_train=train['Rainfall']
X_test=test.drop(['Station','StationIndex','dayofyear'],axis=1)
Y_test=test['Rainfall']

from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.svm import SVC
model = svm.SVC(gamma='auto',kernel='linear')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

Y_pred = model.predict(X_test)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Actual Rainfall': Y_test, 'Predicted Rainfall': Y_pred})  
df1[df1['Predicted Rainfall']!=0].head(10)
```

After this I tried to actually use the model to predict rainfall a few days/months/years into the future. I used a few, like some that are used for stock prices (after adjusting the code). But none of them seem to work.
Since I already trained the model, i thought it would be easy to just forecast a few days in the future. Suppose, I trained with data from 1970-2015, tested with data from 2016. Now I want to predict what the rainfall will be in 2017. Something like that.

My question is, how can I do that in an intuitive way?

I'd be really grateful if someone can answer this question.

Edit @Mercury:
This is the actual result after using that code. I doubt the model is running at all...
This is the image of actual result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Vk1.png

Comment: should I remove the image after the "Edit @Mercury: This is the actual result after using that code. I doubt the model is running at all..." ? 
sorry i am really new to stackoverflow

Comment: Yeah. What has happened with the predictions is that using SVC is actually not a very good modelling of a time series problem. Using SVC treats this as a classification problem (your time series forecasting is actually more similar to regression by the way) and I'm sure the data has an overwhelming amount of 0s (like more than 60%, right?). So what has happened is that the model has learned to predict 0s all the time -  and by doing so it's getting almost 70% accuracy. What you can do is, look into proper time series forecasting methods like hidden markov, autoregression etc.

Comment: i see, i will spend a day or two on that then. and tell here if i get any results. and yes it does have a HUGE amount of 0 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed a very simple mistake here:

```
X_train=train.drop(['Station','StationIndex','dayofyear'],axis=1)
Y_train=train['Rainfall']
X_test=test.drop(['Station','StationIndex','dayofyear'],axis=1)
Y_test=test['Rainfall']
```

You haven't dropped the `Rainfall` column from your training data.

I'll make a bold assumption and say that you get a perfect 100% accuracy in both your training and testing, right? This is the reason. Your model sees that whatever is present in the 'Rainfall' column in the training data is always the answer, so it does exactly that during testing, thus getting a perfect result -- but in truth it's not predicting anything at all!

Try running like this:

```
X_train=train.drop(['Station','StationIndex','dayofyear','Rainfall'],axis=1)
Y_train=train['Rainfall']
X_test=test.drop(['Station','StationIndex','dayofyear','Rainfall'],axis=1)
Y_test=test['Rainfall']

from sklearn import svm
model = svm.SVC(gamma='auto',kernel='linear')
model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
print('Accuracy on training set: {:.2f}%'.format(100*model.score(X_train, Y_train)))
print('Accuracy on testing set: {:.2f}%'.format(100*model.score(X_test, Y_test)))
```

Comment: actually yes the mae was always 0. let me try that and see what the result is.

Comment: Ok i tried a few things. it basically confirms that i have to drop rainfall. or the confidence score is always 1. mae always 0. yikes... but when I drop rainfall from X_train and X_test, the model does not do anything. I try to get results and nothing appears. Is the code wrong on a basic level?

Comment: It should run. It might take a longer time to finish/converge, since the model is actually learning now. If you're using a jupyter environment, try refreshing/restarting the session, and try the code I've included above. model.fit and model.score may take some time to finish running.

Comment: yes i am using jupyter. i will try to do that after clearing and restarting.

Comment: I have added the result in the main post. i tried the same thing in spyder and then pycharm. basically same result (meaning everything is 0)

Answer (score 0):

The Data is very simple. If you are participating in a kaggle competition, then interpretability isn't also a big issue, only the accuracy, you can use any complex model and get good results. However, if I want interpretability, then I would use a decision tree of depth not more than 4. Decrease the depth and you will see more generalized decision trees. It will give you good insights in the data.

Some suggestions could be-

1. Deleting the Day, month columns altogether, that info is already stored in the day of year attribute (leap yrs are not really that much of a problem).
2. You are left with only three columns, year, Station and day of year.
3. See if the Year column is important or not (important decisions of a decision tree is present in first 2-3 depths), If it is not maybe do away with it. In real world, where the changes are a lot more unpredictable, the more the generalized a model, the better it is. The Station and day of year are important considerations and can't be ignored.

Then check for Complex models, Are they increasing your accuracy ? They might.

If they do then use them or else stick to simpler models owing to their high interpretability, faster computation time.

Comment: sorry for late reply. I tried doing this today and i have come to the conclusion that my dataset just does not work well with these algorithms and as one user above said, i should try to use time series. thanks for the tip though, i got to explore some new things i didn't know existed.